# Table-less UNION query in MS Access (Jet/ACE)

Tags: sql, ms-access, jet

This works as expected:

```
SELECT "Mike" AS FName
```

This fails with the error "Query input must contain at least one table or query":

```
SELECT "Mike" AS FName
UNION ALL
SELECT "John" AS FName
```

Is this just a quirk/limitation of the Jet/ACE database engine or am I missing something?

Comment: That is also what I have found, but you can select from any one line table as a work around, or select distinct from any table.

Comment: Yeah, I keep a local Dummy table with 1 field and 1 record and use it like you suggest.  It's just something that's always mildly annoyed me and I wanted to make sure I wasn't missing something simple.

Comment: I've never personally seen any documentation even on MSDN regarding this, as you have already mentioned to get around it use an existing table name.

Comment: The [MS Access reference for SELECT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/select-statement-microsoft-access-sql) does not present the `FROM`as optional. So I guess that this is interpreted somewhere else, where you don't have full SQL. Which seems consistent with [this question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49201428/select-without-from-clause) where Access requires a `FROM` if you put subquery in the mix. .. I haven't tested all these, of course.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You didn't overlook anything.  Access' database engine will allow a single row `SELECT` without a `FROM` data source.  But if you want to `UNION` or `UNION ALL` multiple rows, you must include a `FROM` ... even if you're not referencing any field from that data source.

I created a table with one row and added a check constraint to guarantee it will always have one and only one row.

```vb
Public Sub CreateDualTable()
    Dim strSql As String
    strSql = "CREATE TABLE Dual (id COUNTER CONSTRAINT pkey PRIMARY KEY);"
    Debug.Print strSql
    CurrentProject.Connection.Execute strSql
    strSql = "INSERT INTO Dual (id) VALUES (1);"
    Debug.Print strSql
    CurrentProject.Connection.Execute strSql

    strSql = "ALTER TABLE Dual" & vbNewLine & _
        vbTab & "ADD CONSTRAINT there_can_be_only_one" & vbNewLine & _
        vbTab & "CHECK (" & vbNewLine & _
        vbTab & vbTab & "(SELECT Count(*) FROM Dual) = 1" & vbNewLine & _
        vbTab & vbTab & ");"
    Debug.Print strSql
    CurrentProject.Connection.Execute strSql
End Sub
```

That `Dual` table is useful for queries such as this:

```sql
SELECT "foo" AS my_text
FROM Dual
UNION ALL
SELECT "bar"
FROM Dual;
```

Another approach I've seen is to use a `SELECT` statement with `TOP 1` or a `WHERE` clause which restricts the result set to a single row.

Note check constraints were added with Jet 4 and are only available for statements executed from ADO. `CurrentProject.Connection.Execute strSql` works because `CurrentProject.Connection` is an ADO object.  If you try to execute the same statement with DAO (ie `CurrentDb.Execute` or from the Access query designer), you will get a syntax error because DAO can't create check constraints.

Comment: I'd love to know the reason for the design or see some documentation on the behavior, but enough experienced people have weighed in that I feel confident that this is the answer.

Comment: I haven't seen it documented anywhere.

Comment: I keep a Dummy table which is essentially the same as the Dual table you show here.  Your check constraint is an improvement over what I have.  Whenever I write a query I'm always wary that some day I'll inadvertently add rows to the Dummy table.  I end up taking the extra cautious approach of adding the WHERE clause or TOP 1 (as you also suggest).  Adding the check constraint would give me the confidence to improve the efficiency of those queries (ever so slightly) by dropping the WHERE/TOP.

Comment: Thank you.  @onedaywhen showed me how to use ADO for CHECK CONSTRAINT; you can't do it with DAO.  I appreciate that Dual allows me to write concise single-row queries ... even though I don't actually do it often.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the ADO reqt.  I missed that the first time reading it.  I assume as you've written your code there's no need to actually add ADO as a reference.  Simply using the Execute method off of the CurrentProject.Connection is enough, right?

Comment: Right, CurrentProject.Connection is an ADO object and is available without setting a reference for ADO ... I think starting with Access 2000.  (I'm not positive about when.)

Comment: +1 for "rolling your own" DUAL. I've done something similar in the past, but I've just made [ID] the Primary Key and set a field constraint specifying that ID must have the value 1. (I was using DAO `TableDef` and related objects to create the table.)

Comment: @GordThompson Please correct me if I have this point wrong: Your design would permit no more than one row, but would also allow that one row to be deleted.  I wanted to guarantee `Dual` always contains exactly one row.

Comment: No, you're right, there's nothing preventing that row in my table from being deleted. I'll keep your method in mind the next time something like this comes up!

Comment: You *can* actually do without an additional physical table: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19663932/521799. But I feel that this is really a bit quirky

Comment: I had a working FROM-less query, but run into the same error when using it as record source for a Report.

Comment: "check constraints...are only available for statements executed from ADO" -- a misstatement. Although the Access query designer defaults to ANSI-89 Query Mode, which indeed causes the `CHECK` syntax to fail, you can change the Access query designer to ANSI-92 Query Mode, allowing the syntax to succeed. DAO always uses ANSI-89 Query Mode and ADO always uses ANSI-92 Query Mode. But the designer can use either.

Comment: the problem with select top 1 is that:if table 1 is empty then union returns nothing for the second statement

Answer (score 6):

If you have access to some system tables, you can emulate a dual table this way:

```sql
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MSysResources) AS DUAL
```

Unfortunately, I'm not aware of any system tables that...

- are always available, readable (MSysObjects might not be accessible to every connection)
- contain exactly one record, such as Oracle's `DUAL` or DB2's `SYSIBM.DUAL`

So you'd write:

```sql
SELECT 'Mike' AS FName
FROM (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MSysResources) AS DUAL
UNION ALL
SELECT 'John' AS FName
FROM (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MSysResources) AS DUAL
```

This is what is being implemented as a syntactic element in [jOOQ](http://www.jooq.org), for instance.

Comment: i like this idea. if you know the name of any available system table, you could do something like `FROM (SELECT TOP 1 NULL FROM MSysResources) AS DUAL` .. the `TOP 1` limits to 1 row, and the `NULL` is the single value returned - it removes the need to know any column name. You need just a table name.

Comment: That could work mostly, but from experience, there's always a very subtle caveat in all RDBMS when using `TOP` in some specific case of subquery...

Comment: `MSysResources` is not present in any of the MDB databases I'm working with. I do have `MSysObjects` but I get permissions errors when using them in queries over OLE-DB. Grumble.

Comment: @Dai: you can use any other table

Answer (score 5):

When you have restricted read-only access to the database (i.e you cannot create new tables or access system resources), this could work:

```
SELECT "Mike" AS FName
FROM (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM anyTable WHERE 1=0) AS dual
```

1. *anyTable* is the first user table you find (I can hardly imagine a real-life database with no user table!).
2. *WHERE 1=0* is supposed to return fast a count of 0, even on a large table (hopefully the Jet engine is smart enough to recognize such trivial condition).

Comment: I used your method and created a query named SingleRowQuery: `SELECT Count(*) FROM UserTable WHERE 1=0;` Then I used it in the union query: `SELECT CustNo, CustName FROM Customers WHERE CustNo = 1 UNION SELECT 0, '(NA)' FROM SingleRowQueryORDER BY CustName`

Comment: I like this approach best because it avoids using `MSysObjects` (which often has permissions issues preventing its use). My own version which matches Oracle's `DUAL` is this: `( SELECT TOP 1 IIF( COUNT(*) = 0, 'X', 'X' ) AS DUMMY FROM [anyTable] WHERE 1 = 0 ) AS [dual]`

Answer (score 2):

Here's a much simpler way to do it:

```
SELECT 'foo', 'boo', 'hoo' from TableWith1Row
union
SELECT 'foo1', 'boo1', 'hoo1' from TableWith1Row
```

Important: TableWith1Row can EITHER be a table with literally 1 record (which you ignore anyway) OR it can be a table with any number of rows (must have AT LEAST 1 row) but you add a WHERE clause to ensure 1 row. This is a bit loosy-goosy but it's a quick way to make this work without creating more tables.

Answer (score 0):

If someone wants to use the Top 1 method, it would look like this:

```
SELECT first_name AS FName
FROM tblname
UNION ALL
SELECT "Mike" as Fname
FROM (Select Top 1 Count(*) FROM tblsometable);
```

The alias for the field has to be the same on both sides of the union, in this case "FName".

Comment: Why `Select Top 1 Count(*)`?  Without a `GROUP BY` clause, `Select Count(*)` can only return one row.  What is the advantage of including `TOP 1` there?

Answer (score 0):

Put in any table name (you don't need to actually select a column from it).

This query gives me the 3 fiscal years I need for a dropdown. The fiscal year begins in July.

```sql
SELECT IIf(Month(Now())>6,Year(Now())-1,Year(Now())-2) AS FY
FROM table
UNION 
SELECT IIf(Month(Now())>6,Year(Now()),Year(Now())-1) AS FY
FROM table
UNION 
SELECT IIf(Month(Now())>6,Year(Now())+1,Year(Now())) AS FY
FROM table;
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is a query that actually works in access.  I tested it. It uses a sub-query as "dual" : (SELECT count(*) as cnt from MSysObjects).

```
select 1 as a from (SELECT count(*) as cnt from MSysObjects) UNION ALL
select 2 as a from (SELECT count(*) as cnt from MSysObjects) UNION ALL
select 3 as a from (SELECT count(*) as cnt from MSysObjects)
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it.