# Combo Box with Rowsource Table/query but also with "select nothing" option

Tags: ms-access, combobox, vba

Background:

I am using Ms-Access forms and I have a combo drop-down list that I am coding in VBA

Question:

Is it possible to have a combo based on a query such as: `"SELECT tbl.col1 FROM tbl"`
so you get a dropdown list that is bound...

**BUT....**

ALSO want to add one more to the list... **"None Selected"** at the Top.

If some one has ideas, tips or suggestions then please let me know.

Many thanks!

Some Code:

```
    Me.CboUnallocatedPayments.RowSource = " & _
    "SELECT zTempBankCustomerReceipt.TransType, zTempBankCustomerReceipt.Ref, " & _
    " zTempBankCustomerReceipt.Details,zTempBankCustomerReceipt.EntryDate, " & _
    " zTempBankCustomerReceipt.NetAmt, " & _
    " zTempBankCustomerReceipt.PaidStatus " & _
    " FROM zTempBankCustomerReceipt UNION " & _
    " SELECT 0, "**NOTHING SELECTED**" " & _
    " FROM zTempBankCustomerReceipt" & _
    " WHERE zTempBankCustomerReceipt.TransType = 'SA' " & _
    " AND zTempBankCustomerReceipt.PaidStatus = '0'"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider a union query for your combo box row source.

```sql
SELECT tbl.col1 FROM tbl
UNION ALL
SELECT 'None Selected' FROM Dual;
```

`Dual` is a custom table whose design guarantees it will always include only 1 row.  You can create your own `Dual` table using the instructions at [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7933927/77335).  But you don't need a special table for this purpose; any table or query which returns a single row will be sufficient.

Regarding the ordering of rows within the combo, you can add a second field to the query.  If you want `'None Selected'` at the top of the list, with the remaining rows sorted alphabetically ...

```sql
SELECT 1 AS order_by, tbl.col1 FROM tbl
UNION ALL
SELECT 0, 'None Selected' FROM Dual
ORDER BY 1, 2;
```

Comment: AHA! This is the answer I was looking for! Works perfectly. Thanks for headsup Hansup! ^_^