# Query input must contain atleast one table or query

Tags: ms-access

I have a query in access that is suppose to check whether the item already exists in the database before inserting it:

```
INSERT INTO FinalizedPrintedStickers
Values('0000846043-481-9-0',
'48IG - 1F Straight Panel                                                        ',
'481                               ',
'0',
'0',
'',
'210',
'Printed')
 WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT [SN] FROM FinalizedPrintedStickers Where SN = '0000846043-481-9-0')
```

Now, I've gotten this error before but usually it's when there's no table for example if you "select * from test table" and you type "Select *" and leave out the from clause you get the same error. But I have a table ? Perhaps my where not exists syntax is wrong?

[image]

**Edit:**

Ok, I've added a table "Dual" as suggested with code copy pasted from this question : [Table-less UNION query in MS Access (Jet/ACE)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7933518/table-less-union-query-in-ms-access-jet-ace/7933927#7933927)

Attempting to add a constraint as shown gave me this error :
[image]

after i press ok it highlights the word "Check"

I've never really dealt with constraints (in access atleast..) my syntax is probably wrong

**Edit 2:**

Adding constraints using ctrl G command

[image]

And when I press enter...

[image]

Adding constraints using ADO:

[image]

And when i press run...

[image]

Comment: Shouldn't you put a space between 'values' and the bracket ? Not sure it's needed but worth trying...

Comment: @JustinKirk You must execute that `ALTER TABLE` from ADO.  Use  `CurrentProject.Connection.Execute`

Comment: I'm not using ADO, I'm using oledb xD , There's a way of doing this within access right?

Comment: You can run the command via ADO from a one-off VBA routine. Check out the `CreateDualTable()` routine that @HansUp put in his [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7933927/2144390).

Comment: If you don't want to use my `CreateDualTable` procedure, you can execute that statement with ADO in Access by opening the Immediate window (Ctrl+g), pasting the text from the next comment as a single line, and pressing enter to execute it.

Comment: `CurrentProject.Connection.Execute "ALTER TABLE Dual ADD CONSTRAINT there_can_be_only_one CHECK ((SELECT Count(*) FROM Dual) = 1);"`

Comment: Oh wow i didn't even know you could do that lol, Uh, "Microsoft Access has Stopped working" In the details it just says APPCRASH -_-

Comment: I will just try using ADO in the vb provided with access

Comment: The same thing happens,... Access Just crashes..

Comment: That's surprising and disappointing, Justin.  I've been running that procedure without trouble in nearly all my new dbs the last couple years.  Maybe yours is corrupted.  I would create a new db, and see whether it works there.

Comment: I tried creating a copy of the 2 tables into a seperate database (FinalizedPrintedStickers and Dual) and i get the same error... Maybe if i upgrade my version of access??

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30580/discussion-between-hansup-and-justin-kirk)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is one of those cases where a `Dual` table can be helpful. A `Dual` table is a single-row table that can be used in the FROM clause of a query when you don't really *need* a source table but the SQL parser insists on there being one.

Some database systems (e.g., Oracle) provide a `Dual` virtual table as "standard equipment", but in Access we need to create our own. For an excellent description of the process check out HansUp's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7933927/2144390).

So, once you have your [Dual] table in place, i.e.,

```
id
--
 1
```

...then you can use this query do perform your INSERT (or not...):

```
INSERT INTO FinalizedPrintedStickers
    (
        SN,
        Field2
    )
    SELECT 
        "0000846043-481-9-0" AS SN,
        "48IG - 1F Straight Panel" AS Field2
    FROM Dual
    WHERE DCount("SN","FinalizedPrintedStickers","SN=""0000846043-481-9-0""")=0
```

Comment: Are you sure you have the query right? Select "0000846043-..." From dual will always return false because there's no records in dual.. wont it ?

Comment: @JustinKirk No, the `Dual` table should always have exactly *one* record in it.

Comment: @JustinKirk The Dual table Gord mentioned includes a check constraint which ensures that table always contains exactly one row.

Answer (score 0):

try this you can use simple where Clause

```
INSERT INTO FinalizedPrintedStickers
    Values('0000846043-481-9-0',
    '48IG - 1F Straight Panel                                                        ',
    '481                               ',
    '0',
    '0',
    '',
    '210',
    'Printed')
     WHERE SN Not In(SELECT [SN] FROM FinalizedPrintedStickers Where SN = '0000846043-481-9-0');
```

Comment: FinalizedPrintedStickers is this table Exists or not/

Comment: where Clause required to Remove the duplcate entry in Table.?

Comment: Please check with NOT IN Clause

Comment: Its just Query ot Query in some Language.VB,C#?

Comment: It's taken from C# Code, but i'm testing the query in actual access

Comment: I will create sample.. Let me check inmy system... I