# "Query input must contain at least one table or query" error - nested queries, MS Access

Tags: ms-access, nested

Essentially we are sometimes (?) required to provide a reference to table even if I do not need it. E.g. 
[Query input must contain atleast one table or query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16734142/query-input-must-contain-atleast-one-table-or-query)

The question I have is why query q1 `SELECT 1` executes just fine and gives me 1 row-1 column resultant table with 1 as the value but query q2 `SELECT * FROM q1` produces the aforementioned error?

When I change q1 to `SELECT 1 from dummy_table` where dummy_table is a dummy table with dummy value, q2 runs fine.

Why q1's internal structure is in any way relevant to q2? q1 on its own works just fine. Does the q2 "unrolls" q1 and then compiles a statement 
`SELECT * FROM (SELECT 1)` (which on its own produces the same error). Can I somehow force Access not to peek into parents' internal structure?
Also why `SELECT * FROM (SELECT 1)` gives an error and `SELECT 1` works fine?

Answer (score 9):

Access will only accept a query without a `FROM` clause when the "naked" `SELECT` is used in isolation, not as part of another query.

As you discovered, `SELECT 1` is valid when it is the entire statement.  But Access complains *"Query input must contain at least one table or query"* if you attempt to use that "naked" `SELECT` in another query such as `SELECT q.* FROM (SELECT 1) AS q;`

Similarly, although `SELECT 1` and `SELECT 2` are both valid when used alone, attempting to `UNION` them triggers the same error:

```sql
SELECT 1
UNION ALL
SELECT 2
```

There is no way to circumvent that error.  As you also discovered, saving the "naked" `SELECT` as a named query, and then using the named query in another still triggers the error.  It's just a limitation of the Access db engine, and it's been that way with every Access version I've used (>= Access 2000).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But why? What is the reason for it? It allows for some execution time optimization?

Comment: I don't really know the answer to why.  I suspect support for a naked SELECT used alone was relatively easy to implement.  But supporting a naked SELECT as part of another query required too much additional development effort for the query parser design, and MS decided it wasn't worth the effort.  But that's only speculation.  You'll probably need to ask MS.

Answer (score 2):

We ran into this issue today with error 3067 when trying to add some records to query results using a `UNION` query.

This doesn't work:

```
SELECT 
UserID, UserName
FROM USERS
UNION SELECT
0, 'Add User...'
```

But as pointed out in the original question, if you use a *valid table name*, you can work around the issue.

Simply adjust the code to select a single record (`TOP 1`) from any table. Here I use `MSysObjects` because that should always exist and have records.

```
SELECT 
UserID, UserName
FROM USERS
UNION SELECT TOP 1
0, 'Add User...'
FROM MSysObjects
```

Even though we are technically not using any data from the "dummy" table, it satisfies the compiler requirements for our union query and returns the desired results.