# Add a Percent of Total Column in Access Query

Tags: sql, ms-access, percentage

I have the following query:

```
SELECT [3-2017].[Dealer#], Sum([3-2017].Balance) AS SumOfBalance
FROM [3-2017]
GROUP BY [3-2017].[Dealer#];
```

I want to add a column that returns the percent of grand total for each dealer#. I think I need another single-row query with the totals and join or union somehow, but I'm completely lost.

I've looked through a few different posts and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19692599/adding-a-percent-column-to-ms-access-query) is the top result, but it doesn't solve my problem, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Really best and easiest done in a report. However, try:

```
SELECT [3-2017].[Dealer#], Sum([3-2017].Balance) AS SumDealerBal,    
(SELECT Sum(Balance) FROM [3-2017]) AS SumBalance, SumDealerBal/SumBalance AS DealerPct   
FROM [3-2017]  
GROUP BY [3-2017].[Dealer#];
```

Advise no spaces or special character/punctuation (underscore is only exception) in any names. Better would be DealerNum or Dealer_Num.

Comment: You're right, I do need to change the name. I did try that, and it did work; however, when I applied the filter 'HAVING [3-2017].[Dealer#] >=600', the calculation 'SumBalance' did not adjust.

Comment: Did you apply filter to the inner query?