# Using Combo Boxes to filter a Split Form

Tags: ms-access, combobox, vba

I am utilizing a Split Form in Access and I have three (3) dropdown combo boxes:
ReportedLOB (used in this example)
Account
StandCategory

Each of these combo boxes are tied to the specific Business Unit selected, therefore it limits the amount of items in the Combo box.  I am using the following code for the ReportedLOB:

```
 Private Sub Combo_Reported_LOB_Selection_Change()

' If the combo box is cleared, clear the form filter.
  If Nz(Me.Combo_Reported_LOB_Selection.Text) = "" Then
  Me.Form.Filter = ""
  Me.FilterOn = False

' If a combo box item is selected, filter for an exact match.
' Use the ListIndex property to check if the value is an item in the list.
  ElseIf Me.Combo_Reported_LOB_Selection.ListIndex <> -1 Then
  Me.Form.Filter = "[ReportedLOB] = '" & _
                 Replace(Me.Combo_Reported_LOB_Selection.Text, "'", "''") & "'"
  Me.FilterOn = True
  End If
 End Sub
```

Let's say there are 4 items in the drop down list: MCD, Comp, GRD, DRR
When I select MCD, it filters correctly for MCD results. However, upon review with the team, they want to remove that filter for MCD to have all results again, so I created an extra table an joined it for a **ALL** dropdown item to be added to the list.

```
 SELECT DISTINCT dbo_ztblGAAP_Splits_TableA.ReportedLOB FROM
dbo_ztblGAAP_Splits_TableA WHERE (((dbo_ztblGAAP_Splits_TableA.BU)=[Forms]![Frm_Main]!
[Frm_Main_TextBox_Display_BU_Number_HIDDEN])) 
ORDER BY dbo_ztblGAAP_Splits_TableA.ReportedLOB
UNION ALL 
SELECT Top 10, "**ALL**" FROM  
dbo_tTbl_ADMIN_ForFiltering
ORDER BY ReportedLOB;
```

Now, the million dollar question......When I select **ALL** from the drop-down it changes all my records to **All** versus giving me all the original results for Reported LOB.  Has anyone every dealt with this?  I have searched everywhere to try to piece this code together.

Comment: That `UNION ALL` query is the row source for `Combo_Reported_LOB`, correct?  If so, does it return the correct results when you test it alone as a new query in the Access query designer?  One issue ... `SELECT Top 10, "**ALL**"` ... that doesn't look right to me.

Comment: @HansUp, Correct, and to your 2nd Question - now my results are not working. I know you have commented on issues similar to this and I appreciate your tutelage. I created a table that has two columns: ID and ReportedLOB, ID=1 and ReportedLOB = **ALL**, I must have my joins all screwed up, because it fails. Working on it

Comment: I tried following Microsoft's example [LINK](
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/210290) on how to add an "All" option to a ComboBox in Microsoft Access, but their article does not do an adequate job of providing guidance, aside from specifying the code.

Comment: OK, and you've set your sights on the `UNION` query approach instead of the callback function, right?  That's the better choice because callbacks are more challenging.  Does the query in the following comment give you what you need for the combo's row source.  Use any table or query which returns a single row in place of `Dual`, or [make your own Dual table](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7933927/77335).

Comment: `SELECT d.ReportedLOB FROM
dbo_ztblGAAP_Splits_TableA AS d WHERE d.BU=[Forms]![Frm_Main]!
[Frm_Main_TextBox_Display_BU_Number_HIDDEN] 
UNION
SELECT "**ALL**" FROM  
Dual
ORDER BY 1;`

Comment: @HansUp, yes the callback function is not working at all. Therefore, I placed the code above and the Query works. When I go to the Form and Select **ALL** from the list, my Form Blanks out. Like everything dissappears, white screen. I am guessing my Private Sub Combo_Reported_LOB_Selection_Change() needs to be modified now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now that you have a working row source query for your combo, I'll suggest you use the combo's After Update event to drive changes to the form's `.Filter` property.

```vb
Dim strFilter As String

With Me.Combo_Reported_LOB_Selection
    If IsNull(.Value) Or .Value = "**ALL**" Then
        ' If the combo box is cleared or ALL selected, clear the form filter.
        Me.Filter = vbNullString
        Me.FilterOn = False
    Else
        ' item other than ALL is selected, filter for an exact match.
        strFilter = "[ReportedLOB] = '" & _
            Replace(.Value, "'", "''") & "'"
        Debug.Print strFilter ' check this in Immediate window in case of trouble
                              ' you can use Ctrl+g to go to the Immediate window
        Me.Filter = strFilter
        Me.FilterOn = True
    End If
End With
```

Notice that the combo does not have focus at After Update, so its `.Text` property is not available.  So we use `.Value` instead.  The `.Text` property is really only useful while you're changing the value.  And the combo has focus while you're making those changes, so `.Text` is available then.  Pretty much any other time, use `.Value`.

If you really do prefer to continually change the `.Filter` with each combo keystroke, you will have to adapt the above code for the combo's Change event.

Comment: The aforementioned code works great(thank you). So when I filter for **ALL** it shows in the split table as **ALL** but does not change the Actual SQL data. This is just a filtering mechanism.

Comment: Yes, just a filter mechanism.  But it wouldn't be difficult to alter the form's `RecordSource` instead its `Filter`.  Is that what you would prefer?

Comment: I would rather Lines of Business retain the names versus everything to **ALL**. I think this would confuse the users.

Comment: Doh!  The LOB column displays ALL in the detail rows instead of the actual LOB values ... sorry I didn't pick up on that.  But I have no idea why it is happening.

Comment: Do you think it is because of SELECT DISTINCT in the Query built for that ComboBox? I have to use Distinct in order to limit the drop-down list. Nope that wasn't it. ARgghhh

Comment: I still cannot figure it out. I would be happy to send the stripped down version for you to take a gander at. How do you want me to send it to you?

Comment: Sent you an email, THANKS