# Date/time field/column need query to have distinct dates (without times) & sorted correctly

Tags: ms-access

I have a list of records that have a date/time field/column; I want a query to get just the distinct days (removing the time, like 1/1/14, 1/2/14, etc) & sorted correctly. Its going into a form's combo box row source so a user can filter/narrow-down the info on the screen per day

Here is my original query:

```
SELECT TOP 1 "*** ALL ***" AS ord_tdate FROM qryOrderEntriesNotBilled 
UNION SELECT DISTINCT FORMAT(ord_tdate, "mm/dd/yy") FROM qryOrderEntriesNotBilled
ORDER BY 1;
```

Here is a simplified view for the sake of the question at hand:

```
SELECT DISTINCT FORMAT(ord_tdate, "mm/dd/yy") FROM qryOrderEntriesNotBilled
ORDER BY 1;
```

Both of the above work, but the order is wrong, its obviously sorting by number (1st one) rather than overall value as seen here:

[image]

Things I have tried unsuccessfully:

- `DATEVALUE(ord_tdate)` solved the simplified view, but with original query (union) it doesn't work correctly as seen below
- `CDate(Datevalue(ord_tdate))` & `CDate(FORMAT(ord_tdate, "mm/dd/yy"))` had same results as above

  [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include a second field expression, `DateValue(ord_tdate)`, in the row source query.  Sort by that field.  In the combo properties, select 2 as the column count and set the column width for that second column to zero.

This query returns what I think you want in Access 2007 with *qryOrderEntriesNotBilled* as an actual table instead of a query.

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT
    FORMAT(ord_tdate, "mm/dd/yy") AS date_as_text,
    DateValue(ord_tdate) AS date_as_date
FROM qryOrderEntriesNotBilled
UNION ALL
SELECT TOP 1
    "*** ALL ***",
    Null
FROM qryOrderEntriesNotBilled
ORDER BY 2;
```

My personal preference is to use a custom single-row *Dual* table for the "fabricated" query row.  If you would like to try that approach you can find a procedure to create your own [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7933927/77335).  But a dedicated table is absolutely not a requirement for this.  It's purely a matter of developer preference.

Comment: You're always there for me HansUp. You helped me with the first part of this issue, I am slowly learning Access & SQL better, thanks