# Have blank fields in query on purpose

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a Microsoft Access database with the following table:

```
TableName: Parts
Cabinet ID - Number
Part ID - Number
PartClass - Number
Width - Number (double)
Length - Number (double)
Description - Text
```

I use the following SQL queries to get three views:

```
DoorPanels:
SELECT Parts.[Cabinet ID], Count(Parts.[Cabinet ID]) as Qty, Parts.Description as Name Parts.Width, Parts.Length 
FROM Parts
WHERE PartClass=13 GROUP BY Parts.[Cabinet ID], Parts.Description, Parts.Width, Parts.Length
ORDER BY Parts.[Cabinet ID]

DoorRails:
SELECT Parts.[Cabinet ID], Count(Parts.[Cabinet ID]) as Qty, Parts.Description as Name Parts.Width, Parts.Length 
FROM Parts
WHERE PartClass=14 GROUP BY Parts.[Cabinet ID], Parts.Description, Parts.Width, Parts.Length
ORDER BY Parts.[Cabinet ID]

DoorStiles:
SELECT Parts.[Cabinet ID], Count(Parts.[Cabinet ID]) as Qty, Parts.Description as Name Parts.Width, Parts.Length 
FROM Parts
WHERE PartClass=15 GROUP BY Parts.[Cabinet ID], Parts.Description, Parts.Width, Parts.Length
ORDER BY Parts.[Cabinet ID]
```

This gives me three separate views that hold only the parts that I want.  Now, I have an additional table:

```
TableName: Doors
Cabinet ID - Number
Door ID - Number
Width - Number (double)
Height - Number (double)
```

I use another query to create a view for this as well:

```
SELECT Doors.[Cabinet ID], Count(Doors.[Door ID]) as Qty FROM Doors GROUP BY Doors.[Cabinet ID] ORDER BY Doors.[Cabinet ID]
```

So, finally I want to join all of these together...but this is where I am at a bit of a loss.  What I need to get, would be a result like this, from the data that I have retrieved:

```
Doors.[Cabinet ID]    Doors.Qty    DoorRails.*    DoorStiles.*  DoorPanels*
1                     2            [data]         [data]        [data]
                                   [data]         [data]        [data]
2                     3            [data]         [data]        [data]
                                   [data]         [data]        [data]
                                   [data]         [data]        [data]
```

Now, to decipher what I am talking about in the result above, you can see that for [Cabinet ID] 1, I have a door quantity of 2, so I need 2 records for the parts for that door.  [Cabinet ID] 2 has 3 doors, so I need 3 records for all the door parts for that.

Now, I understand that this is a little complicated, and possibly...well...impossible, but I have been working on this for a few days and haven't come up with anything.  If it's not possible, I would appreciate the experts here telling me so.

Just for FYI - I can't make ANY changes to the database or the structure, all that I can do is run Queries against it.

Comment: This isn't trivial in any database, and is even harder in Access.

Comment: That I understand, hence the need to ask for help.  Of the 300+ queries that I have had to create in the past 2 months for the project I am working on, this is the only one that has truly stumped me.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way to do this would be via a Cartesian join to a table that simply has rows with a single field incrementing from 1 to the maximum number of doors you will ever need.  For example,

```
Counter.Num
-----------
1
2
3
```

If you cannot even create local tables for your own use, you could simulate the above using a UNION query.  Access has some [limitations here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7933518/154439), so you'll need to reference an existing table even though you won't use any of its rows.  For example,

```
SELECT TOP 1 1 AS Num FROM msysobjects
UNION ALL
SELECT TOP 1 2 AS Num FROM msysobjects
UNION ALL
SELECT TOP 1 3 AS Num FROM msysobjects
```

Then use this Counter table/query as follows:

```
SELECT D.[Cabinet ID], C.Num & " of " & Count(D.[Door ID]) AS [Door Number], 
       DR.*, DS.*, DP.* 
FROM Counter AS C, 
     ((Doors AS D INNER JOIN DoorRails AS DR ON D.CabinetID=DR.CabinetID)
                  INNER JOIN DoorStiles AS DS ON D.CabinetID=DS.CabinetID)
                  INNER JOIN DoorPanels AS DP ON D.CabinetID=DP.CabinetID
WHERE C.Num <= Count(D.[Door ID])
GROUP BY D.[Cabinet ID] 
ORDER BY D.[Cabinet ID], C.Num
```

This will be a slightly different result than your sample.  The difference is the Cabinet ID will be repeated for each door.  Since the quantity would also be repeated, I substituted the door number instead (in the form of "1 of 2", "2 of 2", etc.).

Comment: I tried this out and it tells me that `Cannot group on fields selected with '*' (DR).`  Thanks.

Comment: That's true.  I left that in as shorthand because I don't know what fields are in those tables.  You will have to add those fields by name and include them in the Group By clause as well.  You may actually want to use `First` instead of `Group By` if performance becomes an issue: [Optimizing Queries: First vs Group By](http://allenbrowne.com/QueryPerfIssue.html#FirstVsGroupBy).