# How to add custom rows to an SQL query in MS Access?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I tried using UNION but I used to get this message:

> Query input must contain at least one table or query

The query I tried was:

```
SELECT NULL AS ID, NULL AS Item
  UNION 
    SELECT Items.ID AS ID, Items.Item as Item
    FROM Items 
    INNER JOIN People 
    ON Items.PID=People.PID
    WHERE People.Name='John';
```

Both select statements run OK independently.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `Dual` table

```
SELECT NULL AS ID, NULL AS Item
FROM dual
UNION ALL
SELECT i.ID AS ID, i.Item AS Item
FROM Items i
INNER JOIN People p ON i.PID = p.PID
WHERE p.Name = 'John';
```

Comment: I don't believe Access has the Dual table, though if you join your answer with HansUp's from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7933518/table-less-union-query-in-ms-access-jet-ace then it should work.

Comment: It does use DUAL in Access... @Newd

Comment: @Hituptony Are you sure?  Do you happen to have a link that references that?

Comment: @Newd you have to create it, but it can be done. http://gpgonaccess.blogspot.com/2010/03/making-dual-table.html

Comment: @Hituptony I would go ahead and click the link that I posted and review the answer I mentioned :-)

Comment: @Newd You speaka my language.

Answer (score 1):

In MS Access, you will need to use a kludge.  This might work:

```
SELECT TOP 1 NULL AS ID, NULL AS Item
FROM (SELECT TOP 1 *
      FROM ITEMS
      ORDER BY ID
     ) as i
UNION ALL
SELECT Items.ID AS ID, Items.Item as Item
FROM Items INNER JOIN
     People
     ON Items.PID = People.PID
WHERE People.Name = 'John';
```

The only purpose of the subquery is to get a table with one row.  Remember that `TOP 1` in MS Access can return more than one row if there are ties.

Comment: plus 1 for teaching me a new word "kludge"... and a good answer ofc

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify what table you want your data from. Try this:

```
SELECT NULL AS ID, NULL AS Item
FROM Items INNER JOIN People ON Items.PID=People.PID
UNION 
SELECT Items.ID AS ID, Items.Item as Item
FROM Items INNER JOIN People ON Items.PID=People.PID
WHERE People.Name='John';
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps if the union query order is changed to start with the formed query and the null query to follow:

```
SELECT Items.ID AS ID, Items.Item as Item
FROM Items 
INNER JOIN People 
ON Items.PID=People.PID
WHERE People.Name='John'

union 

SELECT NULL AS ID, NULL AS Item
```