# Join Multiple Tables from Different Months

Tags: sql, ms-access

Given that we have 3 tables in MS Access,

table1

```
ID  MyName  Months
111 A         1
222 B         1
333 F         2
444 D         2
555 G         3
666 C         3
```

table2

```
ID  Income  Months
111 500       1
222 900       1
333 800       2
444 6000      2
```

table3

```
ID  Income  Months
555 65656   3
666 77777   3
```

I want to join table 2 and 3 into table 1 so that my return will be
Table_Result

```
ID  NAME    Income  Months
111 A       500        1
222 B       900        1
333 F       800        2
444 D      6000        2
555 G     65656        3
666 C     77777        3
```

How do get the Table_Result?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Table-less UNION query in MS Access (Jet/ACE)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7933518/table-less-union-query-in-ms-access-jet-ace)

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use `UNION` when you can simply use `LEFT JOIN` with `Nz`:

```
SELECT T1.ID,T1.MyName as Name, Nz(T2.Income,T3.Income) as Income,T1.Months
FROM Table1 T1 LEFT JOIN
     Table2 T2 ON T1.ID=T2.ID LEFT JOIN
     Table3 T3 ON T1.ID=T3.ID
ORDER BY T1.ID
```

**Explanation:**

`Nz` function returns the second argument if first argument is `null`. Read more [**here**](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/advanced/nz.php).

**Result:**

```
ID  MyName  Income  Months
111 A       500     1
222 B       900     1
333 F       800     2
444 D       6000    2
555 G       65656   3
666 C       77777   3
```

Sample result in mysql [SQL fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/66f33/3) (used `coalesce` for mysql instead of `Nz`)

Comment: Downvoter, Care to explain? My query will get exactly what OP wants (checked and verified).

Comment: Yeh this is a perfect solution, don't understand downvotes on this

Comment: @Matt: Thanks mate, I don't know who downvoted it. I posted my answer after checking it works.

Comment: There are no constraints posted by OP so its safe to assume that t2 and t3 can contain same id's, in which case neither this or @Matt solution is valid, union is the solution

Comment: @MladenOršolić: Your query only uses Table2 and Table3. Then why did OP add Table1 in his question if there are no relations between those **3** tables? And how do we get the name field? Your comment doesn't make sense.

Comment: It doesnt make sense for ppl that didnt learn much more past simple joins..yea

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
select  a.id,a.Myname,b.income,a.month
from table1 a
join table2 b on a.id=b.id
union all
select  a.id,a.Myname,c.income,a.month
from table1 a
join table3 c on c.id=a.id
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to `UNION` table2 and table3 and then join them on table1:

```
SELECT table1.*, table4.income FROM table1 LEFT JOIN 
  (SELECT * FROM table2 UNION SELECT * FROM table3) as table4 
  ON table4.Months = table1.Months AND table4.ID = table1.ID
```

You first `UNION` both table2 and table3 which will just merge all their contents into one "table4" and the you just perform a `JOIN` on the matching `Months` and `ID`. You eventually might want to remove the condition for the `Months` if you dont actually need it.

Alternatively you could achieve the same result by performing `(table1 JOIN table2) UNION (table1 JOIN table3)`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT A.ID, A.MYNAME, A.MONTHS, B.INCOME
FROM Table1 AS A
INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM Table2 UNION SELECT * FROM Table3) AS B ON B.ID = A.ID
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use sql `UNION` operator to get single recordset from 2 or more tables

```
SELECT ID, Income, Months FROM table2
UNION
SELECT ID, Income, Months  FROM table3;
```

A solution to your question using `UNION` would then be :

```
Select t1.ID, t1.MyName, Table_Result.Income, t1.Months
  from Table1 t1
  join (SELECT ID, Income, Months FROM table2
        UNION
        SELECT ID, Income, Months  FROM table3) as Table_Result on Table_Result.id = t1.id;
```

And in case you want all (duplicate also) values you can use `ALL` modifier for `UNION` operator

```
Select t1.ID, t1.MyName, Table_Result.Income, t1.Months
  from Table1 t1
  join (SELECT ID, Income, Months FROM table2
        UNION ALL
        SELECT ID, Income, Months  FROM table3) as Table_Result on Table_Result.id = t1.id;
```

Here is an [sql fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/66f33/7/0) of the final example

Comment: Doesn't contain name, which is what the OP wanted

Comment: It just took a while to edit it to contain all examples i wanted to provide.