# add a none existing result to SQL

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

So i have a quite strange need. I have to add none existing record to outcome of select query. Why? Query is a source of dropdown options in my Access application and i want to add one other option that is not in any table (as a form of default).

So now i have simple:

```
SELECT rowName FROM verySpecialTable
```

and i want to have

```
(SELECT rowName FROM verySpecialTable) + "default"
```

Can i do it by SQL? or do i have to add dummy record to verySpecialTable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

or you can use existing table itself

```
SELECT rowName FROM verySpecialTable
UNION
SELECT top 1 'default' AS rowName FROM verySpecialTable
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `UNION` to the Dual table.

```
SELECT rowName FROM verySpecialTable
UNION
SELECT 'default' AS rowName FROM Dual
```

Since the Dual table might not exist in your access instance, you can emulate it as explained here: [Table-less UNION query in MS Access (Jet/ACE)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7933518/table-less-union-query-in-ms-access-jet-ace)

Comment: thx! i forgote about simple Select 'made up stuff' FROM idk :D