# SELECT without FROM Clause

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, select

I'm writing a SQL statement for my MS Access database, and the purpose is to count values from 3 different queries, so I tried this way:

```
SELECT(query1 + query2 + query3) AS Qtd
```

Each query returns an unique value from an aggregate function count, i.e, `query1 = SELECT Count(something) FROM Table WHERE...`

Everything should work fine, but MS Access demands a `FROM` clause. When I put a table in that query (not changing the `SELECT` statement above), I end up with tones of rows and each row the result expected from `Qtd` column.

So is there any way to skip the `FROM` Clause or the only option to work around is write `TOP 1` (or `DISTINCT`) to not get tones of duplicated rows because of the unnecessary table in `FROM` clause?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the cross join (comma separated tables) of the aggregate queries:

```
SELECT (query1.CntColumn + query2.CntColumn + query3.CntColumn) AS Qtd
FROM query1, query2, query3
```

Comment: This solution worked fine and seemed to me the simplest one. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You could `union all` the queries and then `sum` all the results:

```
SELECT SUM(cnt)
FROM   (SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM table1 WHERE ...
        UNION ALL
        SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM table2 WHERE ...
        -- Etc..
       ) t
```

Comment: I tried to run in MS Access and I got "Query is to Complex"

Comment: Please post the underlying SQL statement of queries as a calculated column, reserved word, data type handling could be the issue.