# Why does DataType Number increment inside MS Access Append (INSERT INTO) query?

Tags: sql, ms-access, insert-into

I'm running into a puzzling *glitch* with MS Access. When I run an append query on a table with a DataType of Number, instead of assigning the queried value to the cell, it increments the number by the queried value. Here's my code..

```
INSERT INTO Billing ( BillDate, BillAmount, NumActive )
SELECT #8/14/2018# AS Expr1, 100 AS Expr2, Sum(IIf([Members].[Active]=Yes,1,0)) AS Expr3
FROM Members, Billing;
```

Basically, I'm counting the number of active members for a certain period (which currently happens to be 34 members) so I can evenly divide the bill. However, when I run the query, starting with an empty Billing table, I get the following results each time:

- Run 1: Billing.NumActive = Null
- Run 2: Billing.NumActive = 34
- Run 3: Billing.NumActive = 68
- Run 4: Billing.NumActive = 102

[image: Snapshot of my Billing table after 4 queries]

I would expect 34 to be inserted each time since the number of active members didn't change. Any ideas why this might be functioning like this?

The BillingID is an AutoNumber, and the PerPerson column is Calculated. For right now, I'm hard coding the date and amount, but both will eventually be populated via a form.

Comment: That is amusing.  The `select` should be evaluated before the `insert`, so I would classify this as a bug.

Comment: You're generating a cartesian product. Each time you run the query, your sum is multiplied by the number of records in your Billing tabel. Remove the table Billing from your FROM statement.

Comment: Thanks for the insight, Rene.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query is counting the number of active members x times, where x is the number of records in the `Billing` table. This happens, because your query "cross joins" the `Members` and the `Billing` table (creating every possible combination of records of both tables). To avoid this, remove the `Billing` table from the `FROM` clause of your query:

```
INSERT INTO Billing ( BillDate, BillAmount, NumActive )
SELECT #8/14/2018# AS Expr1, 100 AS Expr2, Sum(IIf([Members].[Active]=Yes,1,0)) AS Expr3
FROM Members;
```

Comment: Is there a way to see a visual representation of the cross join?

Comment: The visual representation of the cross join is that there is no connection line between the two table symbols in design view of the query. There is no other visual representation.

Answer (score 1):

You want to `INSERT` a single row.  The `INSERT ... VALUES` form makes more sense to me here.

```sql
INSERT INTO Billing ( BillDate, BillAmount, NumActive )
VALUES (#8/14/2018#, 100, DCount('*', 'Members', '[Active]=Yes'))
```

If your issue with that is the query designer converts it to `INSERT ... SELECT` form, do it without a `FROM` because you don't want to add as many rows as exist in either `Members` or `Billing`, and certainly not as many rows as in the cartesian product of those two tables.

```sql
INSERT INTO Billing ( BillDate, BillAmount, NumActive )
SELECT #8/14/2018# AS Expr1, 100 AS Expr2, DCount('*', 'Members', '[Active]=Yes') AS Expr3;
```

If for any reason you can't get away without a `FROM`, use a table or query which returns only one row.  I use a custom table, [Dual](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7933927/77335), which is guaranteed to hold one and only one row.

```sql
INSERT INTO Billing ( BillDate, BillAmount, NumActive )
SELECT #8/14/2018# AS Expr1, 100 AS Expr2, DCount('*', 'Members', '[Active]=Yes') AS Expr3
FROM Dual;
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to using [`DCount`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51851853/111794), you could use the standard SQL `COUNT` function:

```
INSERT INTO Billing ( BillDate, BillAmount, NumActive )
SELECT #8/14/2018# AS Expr1, 100 AS Expr2, COUNT(*) AS Expr3
FROM Members
WHERE Active = Yes;
```

because an SQL statement without a `GROUP BY` clause and the `COUNT` function will only return a single row.

Comment: So this just counts the rows selected? Thanks for the different persepctive.